# How to get information out of the GUI in order to automate tasks with pyautogui

Tags: python, windows, pywinauto, pyautogui, rpa

I've been doing some simple automations with pyautogui, and one of the biggest challlenges I've found is that pyautogui is blind. It can't see what's going on in the GUI. I would like to extract some of this information so I could write more intelligent programs. I've been thinking in the possibility of taking an screenshot and comparing it with a few possible scenarios and taking decisions acording to that (But it seems a waste of resources). That is only an idea. 
I would like to ask you if you know some simple way to make this kind of scripts "less blind".

Comment: You've added tag `pywinauto` but it's different library. See the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) to check what can be visible to pywinauto.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [UltimateRPA Tools](https://www.ultimaterpa.com/). The automation is written in [Python too](https://www.ultimaterpa.com/documentation/), and it has a tool called [Inspector](https://www.ultimaterpa.com/documentation/inspector.html). Inspector is used for the GUI elements identification.
The downside is that UltimateRPA is paid for commercial use, but you can try it for free.

Comment: One more commercial tool? :) Why not Squish or TestComplete then? Less price? Is this tool supporting custom controls with DLL injection into target process or just vanilla MS UI Automation?